# Javascript sliding vertical pannel toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Have been doing a codeacademy course http://www.codecademy.com/ru/courses/javascript-lesson-951/0?curriculum_id=4fc3018f74258b0003001f0f#!/exercises/6 - making a vertical sliding pannel.
The problem is that these codeacademy guys didn't explain how to make the pannel not only slide down, but also slide back up. I tried to do it myself, but didnt achieve anything. Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
ANIMATION_LENGTH = 400;
$panel = $("#panel");
$tab = $("#tab");
var $isShown;
$tab.click(function($isShown){
    alert($isShown);
    if ($isShown == false)
    {$isShown = true;}
    else if ($isShown == true)
    {$isShown = false;}
    var newTop = $isShown == false ? "-180px" : "0px";
    var lit = {"top": newTop};
    $panel.animate(lit, ANIMATION_LENGTH);
    return $isShown         
});});
```

CSS

```
#panel {
    padding: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #EEE;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:absolute;
    top: -180px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

#tab {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #EEE;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

HTMl

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Result</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="panel.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="panel.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="panel">
        Awesome hidden sliding pane
        <a href="#panel" id="tab">Click to show</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS code as well.

Comment: sure, though there is not much to see. The pannel slides down succesfully, but it doesn't slide back up and alerts show that IsShown var isn't getting modifed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would approach the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/du8z8/3/

HTML

```
<div class="con">
    <div id="tab">Click to Show</div>
    <div id="panel" style="display:none;">
        <p>Awesome hidden sliding pane</p>
        <div id="close">Close</div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#tab").click(function() {
    $("#tab").toggle();
    $("#panel").slideToggle('slow');
});    

$("#close").click(function() {
    $("#tab").toggle();
    $("#panel").slideToggle('slow');        
});
```

CSS

```
    .con { position:relative; }

    #tab {
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        right:20px;
        padding: 10px;
        background: #EEE;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    #close { padding:10px 0 0 0; font-size:0.750em; }

    #panel {
        padding:50px;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:1em;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-weight:bold;
        background:#EEE;
        cursor:pointer;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
    }

​
```

Answer (score 0):

The click listener gets an event passed, not your boolean.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $isShown,
        ANIMATION_LENGTH = 400,
        $panel = $("#panel"),
        $tab = $("#tab");
    $tab.click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $isShown = !$isShown;
        var newTop = $isShown == false ? "-180px" : "0px";
        var lit = {"top": newTop};
        $panel.animate(lit, ANIMATION_LENGTH);       
    });
});
```